# How much trade-route bonus does Arabia get in Civ5?

Tags: civilization-5

The [manual](http://downloads.2kgames.com/civ5/site13/community/feature_manual/Civ_V_Manual_English_v1.0.pdf) states on p173:

> Arabia ... Unique Trait:
>
> Trade Caravan: +2 Gold from each Trade
>   Route.

However, I have seem some references in [other](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7892/is-it-worth-connecting-my-cities-with-roads-early-in-civ-5/8220#8220) answers and comments, that it actually generates +1/trade route.

Which is true?

Comment: I wouldn't rely on the manual, it contains quite a lot of errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is only +1, there must have been some balancing that occurred after the manual was created and they haven't updated it yet.

Comment: This has been observed true through gameplay. Also note that Arabia gains extra oil in the game, which the manual does not mention.