# How much energy is produced by connecting a city to my capital

Tags: civilization-beyond-earth

In Civ: Beyond Earth, the Civopedia tells me that roads cost 1 energy/tile/turn to maintain, but that connecting a city to my capital with a road will give me "a large amount of energy".

How much energy is this? What does the value depend upon?

[Here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7892/is-it-worth-connecting-my-cities-with-roads-early-in-civ-5) is the equivalent question for Civ V. It is obviously not a duplicate, since it refers to a different game, but the mechanics may be similar.

Answer (score 4):

Routes appear to generate 1 energy per citizen in the non-capital city, plus some "base energy per route" amount. These amounts are directly added to your faction-wide income.

Check out the Economic Overview screen. Along the left side under Income will be a section that says "City Connections", you can expand that to see how much each connection is getting you.