# Is there any penalty for building a new city "far away" from your other cities?

Tags: civilization-5

Is there any penalty for building a new city "far away" from your other cities?

That is, if I remember correctly from Civ4, (city) maintenance was higher if a new city was "far away" from my current empire. Is this (still?) true in Civilization 5?

Comment: Oh man I used to hate maintenance.  One of the things I loved most about the [Calabim](http://fallfromheaven.wikia.com/wiki/Flauros)

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom this was posted earlier than the dupe suggestion...

Comment: @Ben But the other question has better answers, so we should make that one the duplicate target.

Comment: That's fair enough

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looking in the manual (bottom of page 75):
"There’s one downside to buildings: most of them cost gold to maintain. The price depends
upon the building in question, and can range from 1 to 10 per turn. The gold is deducted
from your treasury each turn. See “Gold” on page 103 for more details on maintenance." (Page 103 does not provide any more relevant information on this)

So there does not seem to be additional maintenance costs for cities that are further away.
But:
(1) roads costs maintenance now so a road to a city further away will cost more
(2) to get a trade route (which gives additional income) you need to connect a city to your capital which can be more difficult the further away it is.

So in short: no but yes. :-)

Comment: Harbors will let you establish a trade route without keeping up a road - so long as you have coastal cities, don't bother with an expensive road!

Comment: But roads do not cost maintenance if they are outside your borders, so a road connecting two cities across a vast empty continent don't cost any more than if their borders connected.

Comment: @GoatRider: That is false. Roads build by you in neutral territory does cost you money. See http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7936/do-roads-really-cost-gold-to-maintain