# How high is the maintenance for roads (outside of your territory)?

Tags: civilization-5

Regarding road costs in Civ5, [bwarner](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/341/bwarner) [writes](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7936/do-roads-really-cost-gold-to-maintain):

> Based on experience, it appears that
>   you only have to pay 1G for each hex
>   of roads *that are inside your
>   cultural borders*. That means that you
>   don't have to pay to maintain a long
>   road to a city-state if it goes
>   through neutral land

Is this correct? Do I only pay for roads that are inside my borders?

(I think this factor is pretty important when settling a new city further off to get a luxury resource, isn't it?)

Comment: This is incorrect roads outside your borders DO cost gold to maintain, but we should correct the old question rather than opening new question. (I have a screenshot at home set aside for correcting that other question, and I think I will have time tonight...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've already answered this in [my answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7936/how-does-road-maintenance-work/8940#8940) to [Do roads really cost gold to maintain?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7936/do-roads-really-cost-gold-to-maintain). I really believe we can't answer that question without answering this one, making this one a duplicate, but as long as this one is open, I'll help.

Short version:

**Roads you build in *Neutral Territory* cost just as much as road in *Your Territory*.**

How much that is seems to vary by difficulty, see [Do roads really cost gold to maintain?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7936/do-roads-really-cost-gold-to-maintain) for the full chart.

**Roads in *Another Nation's Territory* cost YOU nothing.**

This is the working theory, in need of further testing when I get the chance. Again, see the other question for faster updates, although I will come back here and edit once we have full information.

Finally, as [mpenrow](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8892/how-high-is-the-maintenance-for-roads-outside-of-your-territory/8893#8893) already said, you can get the effects of luxury resources throughout your empire without trade routes, so that is not a concern. And remember the hex with the luxury resource itself does NOT need a road. Roads are really only for moving units and connecting cities for trade in Civilization 5.

Comment: Thanks. That should be sufficient as an answer for now. Now if only I could test more, but loading a game takes about 5 minutes on my PC, so testing with reloading is horrible :-)

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to connect your city via a road in order to get the benefit of a luxury resource. If the resource is in your city and the tile is worked you will get the resource. Reagrdless of having a road. Connecting the city via a road helps with a trade route and troop movement however.

As far as I can tell having a road outside your territory does not cost any gold to maintain.

Comment: You don't have to work the tile to get the resource - the resource doesn't even have to be within working range of one of you cities. In my current game I've just culture-bombed into an unclaimed desert area to secure myself some oil - the resource tile is about 4 or 5 hexes away from my nearest city and is available to use for units.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to pay maintenance for every road you build in neutral territory also, but the cost is some fraction of the regular 1g/road. The exact formula appears to be quite elusive, but I've certainly seen tile maintenance costs go down after destroying some of the roads I built in neutral territory.