# Do other civilizations pay for roads you build in their territory?

Tags: civilization-5

If I build roads in a friendly civilization, are they just free, or does that civilization pay for them, and if they do pay for them is it possible to encumber their economy by filling their nation with roads?

Comment: I'm pretty certain the road builder pays for them. I might do a test tonight.

Comment: IIRC, road builder pays for roads in neutral territory, but the territory owner pays for all roads in territory

Comment: i thought roads built in neutral territory were free?

Comment: @Jimmery: No they aren't free.

This is an interesting question. I'll try this tonight. I'll build every tile of my enemy with road. As a result, he/she would have more maintenance and less income. Bwahahaha.

Comment: Yeah i started doing this, but I couldn't really tell if I was making a difference so I gave up. But if it was possible it could be a good way of passively destroying the economies of your "allies".

Comment: @Jimmery while at the same time vastly improving their infrastructure..  Friend did this to me then tried to attack me but because I had so many roads I could just keep moving units everywhere to counter him.  He lost.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is another similar but broader question [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7936/how-does-road-maintenance-work). The answer left unresolved your particular question - what happens to roads you build in other players borders.

**Short Answer:**
Roads inside a civilization's territory are paid for by the owner of the territory.
Roads outside any borders (neutral territory) are paid for the constructor of the road.

So you *can* theoretically wage economic warfare by building roads in other players land.

Also another nugget - roads that used to be in a civilization's borders (aka when a city is razed) are free - nobody pays for them.

**Sources:**
Some empirical work with screenshot from a hot seat game on settler difficulty, so 3 roads = 1 gold.

You pay for roads outside your territory - 6 roads here
[image: You pay for roads outside your territory - 6 roads here]
Owner of territory pays for roads you build in their territory (view from both sides - 9 roads built by Teal, 3 in Blue, 3 Neutral, 3 in Teal)
[image: Owner of territory pays for roads you build in their territory]
[image: View from the builder's side]
And nobody pays for roads that used to be in someone's territory (screwed up the screenshot from the original owner's side, so you'll have to take my word for it)
[image: The razer]
[Insert missing screenshot]

Also, some quick digging around in the SDK source code. Since my digging was somewhat cursory, there might be some more edge cases around. The relevant code files and functions in the SDK are:

`ChangeBaseImprovementGoldMaintenance()` in `CvTreasury.cpp`, which is called in a variety of functions in `CvPlot.cpp` to remove and add maintenance cost when plot ownership changes, such as

`setOwner()` - note that when ownership is taken of a plot (aka plot becomes part of a civilization's territory), the variable tracking the original constructor is set to nobody

`setRouteType()`  - called by `changeBuildProgress()` when a road is completed, which also calls `SetPlayerResponsibleForImprovement()` if the road is built outside anyone's territory

`setPlotCity()` - only seems to be used when a city is about to be razed, called by `PreKill()` in `CvCity.cpp`

Answer (score -1):

You pay for all of your roads, whether they be in your territory, neutral territory, or allied territory. The upkeep is also paid by you.